# Spring boot Actuator endpoint id with spring boot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Yesterday when I updated the Spring boot 2.0 snapshot, I found my customized actuator endpoint doesn't work well when I use annotation like

```
@Endpoint(id = "setupInfo")
```

I'v got exception message like:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Configuration property name 'management.endpoint.setupInfo.cache.time-to-live' is not valid:

    Invalid characters: 'I'
    Bean: webMetricsFilter
    Reason: Canonical names should be kebab-case ('-' separated), lowercase alpha-numeric characters and must start with a letter

Action:

Modify 'management.endpoint.setupInfo.cache.time-to-live' so that it conforms to the canonical names requirements.
```

if i changed it to:

```
@Endpoint(id = "setup-info")
```

the service will start normally, does anyone know the endpoint id name policy has changed or not ?

Comment: The error message mentions the reason and its pretty clear `Kebab Case` as against `Camel Case` used by you

Answer (score 0):

So the error message says it all. You don't have to change the id of the endpoint, you just need to fix the name of the property.

The annotation processor should sanitize the id of your custom endpoint though (to generate a property with `setup-info` rather than `setupInfo`). I've opened [#11107](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11107)

Comment: I have tested the endpoint id and property, only kebab-case id accepted in the new snapshot version, if I use Camel Case endpoint id, I will get the same error message again.

Comment: I guess this issue comes from Spring-Boot 2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT with Spring Framework 5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT from Nov 20th, If I switch back to Spring-boot 2.0.0.M6+Spring Framework 5.0.1.RELEASE, it works well.
One more issue of this snapshot, only "status" and "info" endpoints can be mapped to the WebMvc, other framework endpoints and customized endpoints can not be mapped to the Webmvc rightly like "/application/status" and "/application/info".